# Is it possible to use 'position relative' more than once in the same html page?

Tags: html, css

I am using 'position relative' and 'position absolute' on my master page.

I have a page that use the above master page,
And I am trying to use in this page the 'Position relative' and 'position absolute' again for 2 other elements, but the element below ('position absolute') in this page is not placed according to the element above his ('position relative') and instead it refers to the 'position relative' of the element in the master page..

Hope is was not too clumsy explanation..

Is it possible to use 'position relative' more than once on the same HTML page??? 
If so, how??

Thanks,
Ef.

Comment: Please post markup and css on jsfiddle.net

Comment: did you solve your problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

To your question: 
**You are not limited on how many elements you want to position relative or absolute.**

However, positioning is quite tricky. Your elements being misplaced most certainly is caused by wrong definitions in your CSS.

I will give a short explanation on how it works:

All elements have standard positioning `static`.

However, you may define `position:relative` on as many elements you like.
Now with `top|left|right|bottom` you can move the element relative to it's original placement. (The original space stays occupied!)

`position:absolute` may also be defined on as many elements as you like, however it works differently:

The element does not occupy it's original placement and is placed relatively to **the first ancestor element** which is not statically positioned. (*I think this is the error you mention - you have a sibling with `position:relative` but the absolute positioned element gets positioned according to the PARENT-element with relative/static position*)

These are only the very basics, for more insight info, [read this article](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/understanding-css-positioning-part-1/).

Comment: @user458695 If an  answer helped you, you should accept it, so the other users can see that you problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Until you add the relevant code/information/demo I cannot answer why you are having an issue with your code and layout, however I can assure you that you can have multiple relatively positioned elements on one page, infact- you can apply and position style to any element as many times as you wish.

```
element { 
    position:relative; 
        }

element2 { 
    position:relative; 
        }
```

You are simply defining rules for elements specifically, there are no rules on the amount of times you can use any rule as the rules are independent of each other.

**Reference**

You should probably read through [this page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm) in order to grasp how element positioning works.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I found the problem, my 'absolute' element was not defined inside the 'relative' element...